# parskip glue doesn't stretch

Tags: spacing, layout, parskip, glue

I was thinking that `\setlength\parskip{2ex plus 5ex}` was supposed to set the default paragraph spacing to 2ex and to a maximum value of 7ex in cases where it helps fill the vertical space of the page.

Why doesn't that happen here?

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setlength\baselineskip{3ex}
\setlength\parskip{2ex plus 5ex}

\section{Title}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Title}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add `\flushbottom` before `\begin{document}`.

[image]

Comment: The problem with that is that  I can't control how much the paragraphs are allowed to stretch.

Comment: @Raphael you control that as in the question although `plus` never sets an absolute maximum, just controls how far glue may stretch before the box is underfull.

Comment: If for example I use `flushbottom` and do `\setlength\parskip{10pt plus 1pt}`, there is a gap a lot bigger than 11pt. If I do`\setlength\parskip{10pt plus 0pt}`, there is a huge gap between the section title and the body.